# Appium usage with installation

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, automation, appium

Can we use Appium without installing it on machine?
Like if I want to use appium library without installing on my machine.
If yes, then what could be the possible steps?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Please, see requirements:

> Your environment needs to be setup for the particular mobile platforms
>   that you want to run tests on.
>
> You also need to download the Appium client for your language so you
>   can write tests. The Appium clients are simple extensions to the
>   WebDriver clients. You can see the list of clients and links to
>   download instructions at the Appium clients list.
>
> Run the command npm install -g appium which will install Appium from
>   NPM

(http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?java#requirements)